# Strange lighting effect in direct3d switches dark and light

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I am drawing a `D3DPT_POINTLIST` and have set my direct3d 9 device to a number of states. I don't want to use lighting, because I just want to show the vertex colors.

Depending on my view matrix, the vertices appear to become dark or light. They change all at once and I can't find any renderstate that solves this problem.

I'll try to keep this as short as possible. If there is info missing, please let me know.

```
struct MyVertex {
    float x, y, z;
    D3DCOLOR color;
};

// In the initialization of the device
g_D3D9Device->CreateVertexBuffer (sizeof(MyVertex)*g_MaxVerts, D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY | D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC, 0, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &g_D3D9DynamicVB, NULL);
```

each frame I set these render states:

```
g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);
g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, FALSE);
g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_ZFUNC, D3DCMP_LESSEQUAL);
g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE, TRUE);
g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);

g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LOCALVIEWER, FALSE);
g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_COLORVERTEX, FALSE);

float size = g_PCManager.GetPointSize();
g_D3D9Device->SetRenderState (D3DRS_POINTSIZE, *((DWORD*)&size));

g_D3D9Device->SetFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ|D3DFVF_DIFFUSE);

// and render
void* vbPtr;// = new char[m_VertsBuff0.size() * sizeof(MyVertex)];
UINT maxverts = std::min(m_VertsBuff0.size(),(UINT)g_MaxVerts);
if(SUCCEEDED(vertexbuffer->Lock (0, 0, &vbPtr, D3DLOCK_DISCARD)))
{
    memcpy (vbPtr, m_VertsBuff0.data(), sizeof(MyVertex) * maxverts);
    vertexbuffer->Unlock ();

    //without setting the streamsource, D3D9 will just take some (undefined) memory to read/draw from
    device->SetStreamSource (0, vertexbuffer, 0, sizeof(m_VertsBuff0[0]));

    // Draw!
    device->DrawPrimitive (D3DPT_POINTLIST, 0, maxverts);
}
```

I would like to note that this is a Unity3D native C++ plugin, so maybe there are some glitches I'm not aware of.

This is what it looks like from different angles:

[image: light version]
[image: dark version]

Comment: Do you use shaders or fixed-function?

Comment: @Dave No, this is everything I've added. There is just my vertex data and `SetFVF` that tells what my vertex data looks like.

Comment: @zdd The flickering effects that is not supposed to be there when looking from different angles. It is really on or off and not a nice gradient or so. I only want this to be light, not dark.

Comment: So you did'not setup pixel pipeline at all? It means that you inherit settings from previous draw call. try this code before DrawPrimitive:
device->SetPixelShader( NULL )
device->SetTextureStageState( 0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1 )

Comment: code:

device->SetPixelShader( NULL );
device->SetTextureStageState( 0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1 );
device->SetTextureStageState( 0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1, D3DTA_DIFFUSE );
device->SetTextureStageState( 1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_DISABLE );

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add some texture stages before actually drawing the object.

```
device->SetTextureStageState (0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
device->SetTextureStageState (0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_CURRENT);
device->SetTextureStageState (0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
device->SetTextureStageState (0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_CURRENT);
device->SetTextureStageState (1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);
device->SetTextureStageState (1, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);
```